# MySQL query for row sequences

Tags: mysql, database

Is there a way to express the following query in MySQL:

Let a table have types of rows A, B, C, D, E ... Z and each row represents an event. Find the timestamps and ids of all event sequences A, .. , B, ... , C ordered by timestamp so that timestamp(C) - timestamp(A) < Thresh.

For example consider the following table

```
| type | timestamp |  id |  
|------+-----------+-----|
| Z    |     19:00 |  20 |  
| A    |     19:01 |  21 |  
|      |           |     |  
| .    |       ... |  .. |  
|      |           |     |  
| A    |     20:13 |  50 | *
| B    |     20:14 |  51 | *
| D    |     20:17 |  52 |  
| C    |     20:19 |  53 | *
|      |           |     |  
| .    |       ... |  .. |  
|      |           |     |  
| A    |     22:13 |  80 | *
| D    |     22:14 |  81 |  
| B    |     22:15 |  82 | *
| K    |     22:16 |  83 |  
| J    |     22:17 |  84 |  
| C    |     22:19 |  85 | *
|      |           |     |  
| .    |       ... |  .. |  
|      |           |     |  
| A    |     23:13 | 100 |  
| B    |     23:14 | 101 |  
| C    |     23:50 | 102 |
```

The rows that the query with Thresh = 10mins should yield something along the lines of:

```
| A_id | B_id | C_id |
|------+------+------|
| 50   | 51   | 53   |
| 80   | 82   | 85   |
```

See how the last triplet of A, B and C is not present. The time distance between the last A event and the last C event is more that Thresh.

I suspect that the answer would be something along the lines of "MySQL is not the right tool if you need to ask this kind of question". In that case the followup is, which database is a good candidate to handle this kind of task?

Edit: provided an example

Comment: Can you give better example?  It is unclear what you are asking.  It seems like you might be asking how to find a rows combinations where the difference between their timestamps is less than some value, but I am not sure.

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can express this using a self join:

```
SELECT A.id as A_id, B.id as B_id, C.id as C_id
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM the_table
  WHERE type = 'A'
) A
JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM the_table
  WHERE type = 'B'
) B
JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM the_table
  WHERE type = 'C'
) C ON (
  (C.timestamp - A.timestamp) < 10 -- threshold here
  AND B.timestamp BETWEEN A.timestamp AND C.timestamp
)
```